# Interactive Broker Client Web Portal server not working in EC2

Tags: interactive-brokers

I can get everything working locally. However when I deploy the server to AWS EC2, it doesn't work. I made sure the following configs are done correctly.

- EC2 firewall allows the port traffic to come in
- In the "conf.yaml" file, I configured the port correctly
- In the "conf.yaml" file, I configured my home IP address correctly

When I open the login page, it sometimes renders properly and sometimes it doesn't. I have to keep refreshing the page until it does. So the web page's asset files are not coming over consistently. And then when I manage to login, I do see the session connected properly, however when I try the "/v1/api/sso/validate" GET HTTPS request, I get 401 Unauthorised.

The fact that the SSO login worked correctly tells me my IP address was allowed the access. But me having to refresh multiple times until the login page renders correctly feels weird. Also the `/v1/api/sso/validate` not working is flat out incorrect.

Comment: I'd ask your question in the [TWS API forum](https://groups.io/g/twsapi/topics).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have posted it there as well.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to make it work?